# Pyspark: Row count is not matching to the count of records appended

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to identify and insert only the delta records to the target hive table from pyspark program. I am using left anti join on ID columns and it's able to identify the new records successfully. But I could notice that the total number of delta records is not the same as the difference between table record count before load and afterload.

```
delta_df = src_df.join(tgt_df, src_df.JOIN_HASH == tgt_df.JOIN_HASH,how='leftanti')\
            .select(src_df.columns).drop("JOIN_HASH")  
delta_df.count() #giving out correct delta count
delta_df.write.mode("append").format("hive").option("compression","snappy").saveAsTable(hivetable)
```

But if I could see delta_df.count() is not the same as count( * ) from hivetable after writting data - count(*) from hivetable before writting data. The difference is always coming higher compared to the delta count.

I have a unique timestamp column for each load in the source, and to my surprise, the count of records in the target for the current load(grouping by unique timestamp) is less than the delta count.

I am not able to identify the issue here, do I have to write the df.write in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the line delimiter. When the table is created with spark.write, in SERDEPROPERTIES there is no line.delim specified and column values with * were getting split into multiple rows.

Now I added the below SERDEPROPERTIES and it stores the data correctly.

'line.delim'='\n'